# Jenkins how to set httpListenAddress

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, http, jenkins

I need to hide Jenkins behind the Apache proxy because Jenkins does not run on https. So I started with [this article](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-apache/) where is warning **Make sure that you change the Jenkins httpListenAddress from its default of 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 or any Apache-level restrictions can be easily bypassed by accessing the Jenkins port directly.** But there is no explanation how to do it. So the question is how to set httpListenAddress in Jenkins? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the article from my question there is config file in /etc/default/jenkins and the is also the option --httpListenAddress. Hope it is what I search for.

**EDIT**
The setting is there but is does not affect that Jenkins is available via port 8080 from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`httpListenAddress` is a command-line argument when starting Jenkins:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/#networking-parameters

Depending on your installation there may be various ways to set it. With the systemd configuration in the official packages, using `systemctl edit jenkins.service` to add this should work:

```ini
[Service]
Environment=JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```